# How to override a theme template file with a child theme template file (of the same name)

Tags: child-theme

In my main theme `functions.php` I have:

```
require_once (THEME_PATH . "/woocommerce/tw_woocommerce.php");
```

So I created a woocommerce folder in my child theme folder and copied the `tw_woocommerce.php` file. However it is still the main theme `tw_woocommerce.php` that is used by WP.

Why and how to make it use my child theme copy of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Directly from Woocommerce:

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

> The template files of WooCommerce contain the markup and template
>   structure for the front-end (and HTML emails) of your store. If you
>   open these files you’ll notice they all contain many hooks which will
>   allow you to add / move content without having to edit the template
>   files themselves. This method protects even further against any
>   upgrade issues as the template files can be left completely untouched.
>
> Alternatively, you can edit these files in an upgrade safe way through
>   overrides. Simply copy it into a directory within your theme named
>   /woocommerce, keeping the same file structure.
>
> Example: To overide the admin order notification, copy:
>   woocommerce/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php to
>   yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/admin-new-order.php The copied file will
>   now override the WooCommerce default template file. Do not edit these
>   files within the core plugin itself as they are overwritten during the
>   upgrade process and any customisations will be lost.
>
> The  template files can be found within the /woocommerce/templates/
>   directory.

Comment: Thanks but this file doesn't belong to the actual Woocommerce plugin, it merely belongs to the "Woocommerce integrated" part of the theme, a folder containing only 3 files and 2 folders.

Answer (score 0):

Your parent theme (if you built it) should be using `get_template_part()` instead of `require_once()`. Using `get_template_part()` is functionally equivalent (actually, it's better) and will allow the override ability you're expecting.

I'm assuming the `THEME_PATH` constant does not account for whether the active theme is the child or parent, and therefore, the `require_once()` function will always look for the version in the parent theme, even when located in a template in a child theme.